# A stacktrace pointing to a path on the build server?

Tags: debugging, tfs, stack-trace

The installation of a service faulted, because a wcf service was wrongly configured.

I was surprised, when reading the stacktrace of the exception in the event log, that (only) the last entry of the stack traced to a path on the original tfs build server. The automated build finished without errors of course.

Can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you see is the path of the code file where the exception occured during build time. As far as your assembly was build using the TFS build server, the path of the file is located on the build server. If you would have build the assembly on your developer machine, the path would lead to your dev machine.

Comment: So this in fact completely normal behaviour, I just never noticed it?